# Find the flux of $\vec{F} = 2 x^{2} \,\hat{\imath} - 3 y^{2} \,\hat{\jmath} - 2 z^2 \, \hat{k}$ in $(-4,5,-1)$.

Tags: calculus, integration, gaussian-integral

$S = 
    \lbrace
        (x,y,z) \: | \:
        (x + 4)^2 + (y-5)^2 + (z + 1)^2 = 9
    \rbrace$

Find the flux of $\vec{F} = 
   2 x^{2} \,\hat{\imath} - 3 y^{2} \,\hat{\jmath} - 2 z^2   \, \hat{k}$ in $(-4,5,-1)$.

My attempt:

Using Gauss theorem $$ \int_S
    \vec{F} \cdot \hat{n} \, dS = \iiint_V \nabla \cdot \vec{F} dx dy dz$$

$\nabla \cdot \vec{F} dx dy dz=4x-6z-4z=4(-4)-6(5)-4(-1)=-42$.

Therefore,$\iiint_V \nabla \cdot \vec{F} dx dy dz= \iiint_V-42 dx dy dz$.

Denote $x = ρ\cosθ\sinϕ,y = ρ\sinθ\sinϕ,z = ρ\cosϕ$.

$∫_0^\pi∫_0^{2\pi}∫_0^3-42\cdotρ^2\sin(ϕ)dρdθd=1512\pi $

My solution is wrong , can't find out the problem, appreciate any help.

Comment: What is the source of the question?

Comment: Your last triple integral is negative and evaluates to $-1512 \pi$

Comment: @BobDobbs homework

Comment: @gpmath there is no problem with my answer $\iiint_V \nabla \cdot \vec{F} dx dy dz= \iiint_V-42 dx dy dz$ ?

Comment: What is flux in a point?